# Why is code loading before doctype

Tags: mediawiki

```
<?php

# Alert the user that this is not a valid access point to MediaWiki if they try to access the special pages file directly.
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    echo <<<EOT
To install my extension, put the following line in LocalSettings.php:
require_once "$IP/extensions/Userprofile/Userprofile.php";
EOT;
    exit( 1 );
}


$wgExtensionCredits['specialpage'][] = array(
    'path' => __FILE__,
    'name' => 'Userprofile',
    'author' => 'matsuiny2004',
    'url' => 'http://localhost/mywiki/index.php/Extension:Userprofile',
    'descriptionmsg' => 'userprofile-desc',
    'version' => '0.0.0',
);

$wgAutoloadClasses['SpecialUserprofile'] = __DIR__ . '/SpecialUserprofile.php'; # Location of the SpecialMyExtension class (Tell MediaWiki to load this file)
$wgMessagesDirs['Userprofile'] = __DIR__ . "/i18n"; # Location of localisation files (Tell MediaWiki to load them)
$wgExtensionMessagesFiles['UserprofileAlias'] = __DIR__ . '/Userprofile.alias.php'; # Location of an aliases file (Tell MediaWiki to load it)
$wgSpecialPages['Userprofile'] = 'SpecialUserprofile'; # Tell MediaWiki about the new special page and its class name

function extensionFunction() {
    # Assume $title is the title object
    if( $title->isProtected( 'edit' ) ) {
       # Protected from editing, do things
    } else {
       # Not protected from editing
    }
 }

//test code here


echo '<div id="navigation">Navigation</div>';
?>

<?php
echo '<div id="account">account</div>';
?>

<?php
echo '<div id="editpage">edit page</div>';
?>

<div id='border-search'>
<img src="http://s6.postimage.org/z6ixulv6l/searchbox_border.png"></img>
</div>
?php>

<div class='rectangle-box'>
    <div class='rectangle-content'></div>
</div>
```

I am including extra php and html code from a seperate file that I load as an extension in mediawiki to create a custom layout. the problem is that the code loads before the doctype making the page render in quirks mode in IE and safari. How can i get it to load after the doctype tag?

Comment: It is hard to tell how to do it without the exact code you are running.

Comment: added all the code for page after it loaded

Comment: @user47759: No, we need to know the PHP code you are using for your extra file, and how you you include that. Looks like you don't hook into MediaWiki properly.

Comment: ok. i included the setup file that the extension loads the code from.

Comment: it has no hooks. im not very exerienced with them.

Comment: @user47759 You will need to use a hook, to tell MediaWiki *when* to execute your code. Your current code is run before MediaWiki even starts building the page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have top-level `echo` statements all over your code (by top level I mean ones that are not included in any function).  Which is why the PHP engine executes them as soon as it sees them, which is before the MediaWiki itself starts running.

MediaWiki has some [good documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) explaining all kinds of hooks.  What you should do is write a few **functions** and place all your `echo`-ing code there, and expect this function to be executed when the event in question occurs.

I see a good starter page [here](http://www.organicdesign.co.nz/MediaWiki_code_snippets).  Relevant example is:

```
$wgHooks['ArticleSave'][] = 'wgAddStub';
function wgAddStub( &$article, &$user, &$text, &$summary, $minor, $watchthis, $sectionanchor, &$flags, &$status ) {
    $text = ( $article->exists() ? "" : "{{stub}}\n" ) . $text;
    return true;
}
```